# Elementos únicos de uma matriz

Tags: c

Ao ler uma matriz de ordem *n* x *m* em que n e m sejam maiores que 0 e menores ou iguas a 10, quero ler os elementos desta matriz e verificar quais são os elementos únicos desta matriz, mas ao passar elemento por elemento, não estou obtendo o retorno desejado, minha idéia é transformar essa matriz em um vetor de tamanho n*m e depois ir comparando ele, aqui está meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main ()
  {
    int cont=0, l, c, i, j, m, n, mat[10][10], vet[100], h=0;

   // leitura das dimensoes da matriz 
   scanf ("%d %d" ,&l ,&c);

   //caso as dimensoes nao sejam do tamanho desejado pelo exercicio 
   if (l<=0||l>10||c<=0||c>10){
   printf("dimensao invalida\n");
   return 0;
   }



   else 
   {

    //leitura dos elementos da matriz    
    for (i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
          scanf("%d" ,&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //transformacao da matriz em um vetor 
    for (i=0;i<l;i++)
    { 
        for (j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
          vet[h] = mat[i][j];
          h = h + 1; 
        }
    }

    //comparacao de elemento por elemento 
    for (i = 0; i < (l*c); i++) 
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < (l*c); j++) 
        {
            if (vet[i] != vet[j] && i!=j) 
            {
            printf("%d" ,vet[i]);
            cont++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf(" %d" ,cont);

    }    
    return 0;
    }
```

Sei que o problema está na comparação de matrizes, no entanto a minha dúvida é: 
Tenho que utilizar uma função que compare os elementos do meu vetor e consequentemente utilizar um ponteiro ? Consigo fazer essa comparação com os elementos da minha matriz sem converte-la para um vetor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lógica que está no ultimo `for` não serve para o que você pretende, este:

```
for (i = 0; i < (l*c); i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < (l*c); j++) {
        if (vet[i] != vet[j] && i!=j) {
            printf("%d",vet[i]);
            cont++;
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui você percorre cada elemento e para cada elemento na frente desse, se for diferente conta um. Então imaginando que tem o vetor `[1, 2, 3, 4]` Vai contar 3 quando vai no primeiro, contar dois quando vai no segundo e por ai em diante. Isto não representa a lógica que você quer.

Em acréscimo o passar da matriz toda para o vetor é desnecessario e apenas complica a solução. Uma solução simples é ir passando cada elemento da matriz para o vetor se esse elemento ainda não lá existir.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int existe(int vet[], int tamanho, int valor){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; ++i){
        if (vet[i] == valor){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    int l, c, i, j, mat[10][10], vet[100], unicos=0;

    scanf ("%d %d",&l,&c);
    if (l <= 0 || l > 10 || c <= 0 || c > 10){
        printf("dimensao invalida\n");
    }
    else {
        for (i=0; i<l; i++){
            for (j=0; j<c; j++){
                scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                //aqui passa cada elemento para o vetor de unicos apenas se não existir lá
                if (!existe(vet, unicos, mat[i][j])){
                    vet[unicos++] = mat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d", unicos);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qcmfyF)